# Mathoverflow links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, mathoverflow

Sometimes, I would like to reference a link from MO and it would be helpful if it got immediately turned into the title without having to type it and then include the hyperlink i.e.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145606/on-the-pathwise-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-sdesstochastic-differential-equation

versus

[On the pathwise uniqueness of solutions of SDEs(Stochastic Differential Equations)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145606/on-the-pathwise-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-sdesstochastic-differential-equation).

Comment: This is a cross-website feature, so it's unlikely to be implemented anytime soon. You should also consider asking it on [meta.se].

Comment: ok I did https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394851/mathoverflow-links

Comment: *without having to type it* --- FYI, I never type the titles. I just copy and paste them, selecting "Edit" first if I even suspect there might be MathJax in it.